# Inner join SQL with like operator

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

I have my main table that has a column for a search query.
A simplified example:

Querytable

```
id   query
1    hello new york
2    no information here
3    madison festival
```

Geotable

```
id   suburb     postcode
11    new york   123
12    brooklyn   345
13    madison    999
```

If the search query has a location, I want to retrieve the postcode in a sample result as follows:

```
id     query             suburb      postcode
1      hello new york    new york    123
3      madison festival  madison     999
```

I'm at the moment doing this via SQL and returns the desired result (almost: with  errors like if `inform' is a suburb it will be retrieved although we want to match full words).

```
SELECT QT.id, query, suburb, postocde
FROM Querytable as QT
INNER JOIN Geotable ON query LIKE concat('%',suburb,'%');
```

Since the above tables are large how can I improve this query? Or is there a better way to tackle this problem?

Comment: You can't use something like `LIKE CONCAT('suburb, '%')` - your query will then be able to use an index (sargable). You could use a `COMPUTED` column to capitalise evertything - i.e. New York becomes NEW YORK - easier for searching! PostgreSQL has these.

Comment: @Vérace: No, sadly Postgres does not have computed columns.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for the heads up on that - the Postgres team should definitely consider them - they are a godsend. You could also do it using a `TRIGGER` or using a `VIEW` and `SELECT`ing from that!

Answer (score 0):

from your table, i think the JOIN should be on column ID and your LIKE should be in WHERE, not in JOIN. so something like this instead

```
SELECT QT.id, query, suburb, postocde
FROM Querytable as QT
INNER JOIN Geotable GT ON QT.id=GT.id 
WHERE query LIKE concat('%',suburb,'%');
```

but even with that,  if `inform' is a suburb it will be retrieved since it match the like '%inform%' condition. do you have index in that table to improve performance? in which column you put the indexes?

Comment: QT.id and GT.id is unrelated so cannot join on them. The query I have retrieves the output I have given.

Comment: well, from your data i thought that id is a FK since it looks like id 1 in GT (suburb new york) match with id 1 in QT (hello new york query), same with id 3 (both of them refer to madison). sorry for that

Comment: oh yes! that does look confusing. will fix it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did some changes in your query and gives the desired result for me. Try this.

```
SELECT QT.id, query, suburb, postcode
FROM Querytable as QT
INNER JOIN Geotable ON concat(query,Space(1)) LIKE concat('%',suburb,'[ ]%')
```

Comment: This syntax does not seem to work on postgresql. I tried with a manually added space, but id=2 was still retrieved.

Comment: I tried in MSSQL and it looks good for me, return only 1 and 3